# how does `ls "*" 2>&1 | tee ls.txt` work?

Tags: bash, tee

I was finding a way to save all output to a file and print it.

And the command like the following does work perfectly!

`ls "*" 2>&1 | tee ls.txt`

But I think I don't understand it well.

And I tried `ls "*" | tee ls.txt`. It doesn't work. The error message was not saved into `ls.txt`.

Also I tried `ls "*" 1>&2 | tee ls.txt`. It behaved some strange. What happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`2>&1` says "redirect stderr (2) to wherever stdout (1) goes". `1` and `2` are the file descriptors of `stdout` and `stderr` respectively.

When you pipe `ls` output to `tee`, only stdout goes to `tee` (without `2>&1`). Hence, the error messages are not saved into `ls.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use:

```
ls "*" |& tee ls.txt
```

to pipe both stdout and stderr to `tee` command.

`ls '*'` is actually trying to list a file with the name as `*` since `'*'` is inside the quotes.

Your command:

```
ls '*' 2>&1 | tee out
```

works by by first redirecting stderr(2) to stdout(1) then using the pipe to `tee`

Comment: `ls "*" |& tee ls.txt` does not work on my mac. `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token \`&'`

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned by **l3x**, you are redirecting the "standard error: 2" to "standard output: 1".
The solution is to trigger the redirection before the actual error occurs. So instead of using

`ls "*" 2>&1 | tee ls.txt`

You should use

`ls 2>&1 "*" | tee ls.txt`

This way the "standard error" will not be empty, and will be redirected to "standard output" and the tee will work because "standard output" will not be empty.
I already tested it and it works.
I hope that this was helpful